# second this is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a checkbox, I want to get the check box's data-id value and then check or uncheck another checkbox with the same data-id, but there seems to be some problem here:

```
var data_id=this.attr('data-id');
alert(data_id)
```

What's the problem?

---

```
$('.item').click(function(event) {  //on click  
          if(this.checked) { // check select status
                    var data_id=this.attr('data-id');
                    alert(data_id)
                    /*$(".item[data-id='Companies']").each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                  this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "selectitem"              
              });*/
          }
```

Comment: You should create a jQuery object for using jQuery object's methods!

Comment: Try `$(this)` instead of `this`

Comment: Please [read the jQuery tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/#inside-the-event-handler-function): *"In addition to the event object, the event handling function also has access to the DOM element that the handler was bound to via the keyword `this`. To turn the DOM element into a jQuery object that we can use jQuery methods on, we simply do `$( this )` ..."*

Comment: @Vohuman what do you mean?

Comment: @peyman: `attr()` is a *jQuery* function -- it only works on jQuery-wrapped elements. `this` inside the click event is a plain DOM element, not a jQuery one. You need to first wrap it via `$(this)` before you can access the jQuery methods, i.e.: `$(this).attr('data-id')`. Secondly, you should be using `.data()` to access data attributes: `$(this).data('id')`.